# Error de match con expresiones regulares en preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

El problema es que al hacer un `match` de cada aparición de un carácter `regex` del *string* me retorna todo bien, pero el primer resultado siempre le falta el último carácter.

```
$string = "@user#12458 y @user2#12345 son dos apariciones";
preg_match_all('/\@(.*?)\#([0-9]*5)/i', $string, $mentions, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($mentions as $user){
    $x = $user[1];
    $x = $user[2];
    $getUser = $connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM x WHERE x =:x AND x =:x");
    $getUser->bindParam("x", $x);
    $getUser->bindParam("x", $x);
    $getUser->execute();
    $userId = $getUser->fetch();
    if ($userId>0) {
        echo "hay";
    }else{
        echo "no hay";
    }
}
```

El código de arriba tiene una función **pregmatchall** con la expresión irregular que se supone que debe encontrar todo lo que tenga un *@, letras, # y números*, soy nuevo en esto de las `regex` así que tuve que consultar si estaba bien y me dijeron que así es, pero no sé porque a la hora de hacer `$user[1]` de el primer resultado, me devuelve "1245", dejando de lado al 8 que es el último carácter, pero en el segundo resultado y `$user[1]` me devuelve el numero completo.

Probé editando el `*5` por `*` y no hay problemas, pero también pierde el chiste el la función, porque sólo quiero que sean 5 carácteres después de 5, esto sólo me pasa en `php`, no me pasa en `js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema esta en la `regex`, la misma debería ser la siguiente **`\@(.*?)\#([0-9]{5})/`**.

---

El porque del error es el siguiente:

> `{5}` Indica que debe el resultado del `token` anterior debe
>   coincidir con la cantidad especificada, en este caso exactamente *5*.
>
> `*5` Indica que cualquier cantidad del `token` anterior ( 0 o mas) y que debe
>   coincidir con el *5* al final